# Force image size for Facebook post feed

Tags: image, facebook, post, resize, feed

I'm using PHP Graph SDK to publish posts with images on Facebook, the source image size is 900x900px.

This is my code in summary:

```
require_once('php-graph-sdk-5.x/src/Facebook/autoload.php');

$fbk_appid = 'xxxx';
$fbk_appsecret = 'xxxx';
$fbk_tokenpage = 'xxxx';
$fbk_pageid = 'xxxx';       

$picture = 'img1.jpg';
$link = 'https://www.mysite.ext/page.html';
$message = 'My message';            
$name = 'Title under image'; 
$tags = '#tags...';
$description = 'Description under title';                               

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $fbk_appid,
    'app_secret' => $fbk_appsecret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v3.3'
    ]);
    
try{
    $response = $fb->post('/'.$fbk_pageid.'/feed',
            array (
                'picture' => $picture,
                'link' => $link,
                'message' => $message,          
                'name' => $name,
                'description' => $description,          
            ),
            $fbk_tokenpage
    );
}catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e){
    // Error Graph ( $e->getMessage() )         
}catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e){
    // Error SDK ( $e->getMessage() )           
}
    
// $response->getGraphNode(); //e.g. {"id":"1446491425007649_523376413379549"}
```

Upon publication the image is always resized to 1200x628px.
How to force a custom image format (square for example)?

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't much you can do. The recommendations are about _getting_ that 1200*630 format, not avoiding it :-) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/images Really small square images might get you the square format, but you are not able to "choose" different aspect ratios.

Comment: Thank you CBroe for reply, the og:image tag allows you to specify the dimensions inside html page but this is not my case, I made several attempts but fbk always forces two formats: very small (square) and large (rectangular). I'm seeing some image square large posts from big brands too, but all done manually?

Comment: Or perhaps not normal posts, but ads? For those the rules are different, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved!
instead of /feed i used /photos, like this:

```
$response = $fb->post('/'.$fbk_pageid.'/photos',                    
                array (
                    'message' => 'Head text', 
                    'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('https://www.mysite.ext/img.png')
                ),                  
                $fbk_tokenpage
            );
```